# How do I get Chromium or Firefox manage multi touch events properly?

Tags: firefox, chromium, multi-touch

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have a multitouch capable screen (3M MicroTouch USB controller) but can't get any touch events inside a browser window (Firefox or Chromium).

I see all gestures with `geistest -w WINDOWID` program. I have a multitouch demo tetris program which works. So basically the touch screen is supported on a lower level, but both browser applications don't get any touch events, only mouse events.

What do I have to do to get a proper setup for this?

Answer (score 1):

Run command:

```
chromium --enabled-pinch
```

for
context menu

create shortcut application (.desktop) in

`/home/"your user"/.local/share/applications`

OR

support all aplications

search:

multi touch compiz plugin

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rY-85BUqWgY

Comment: Sorry to remove the Portuguese part - I assume it says the same as the English. But is seems to be longer, can you add to the english text if something is missing? You can edit with the link "edit". You can see the earlier version in the edit history with the link "edited... ago"